# Set up a multi-cloud in a Google cloud enviroment

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do Set up a multi-cloud SSO, in a Google cloud environment, that enable AWS and Azure to exchange data?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up [single sign-on](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-active-directory-configuring-single-sign-on) between active directory environment and Cloud Identity or G Suite account by using Microsoft [Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/active-directory-federation-services), and [SAML Federation](https://www.oasis-open.org/standards#samlv2.0).

You may want to look at this [link](https://www.inqdo.com/how-to-setup-sso-single-sign-on-between-aws-and-google-apps/?lang=en) to set up single sign on between AWS and Google Apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google as an identity provider for the SSO for AWS and Azure. Please use the following links.

For AWS [Link-1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-g-suite-as-external-identity-provider-aws-sso/) and [Link-2](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6194963?hl=en) on how to use g-suite as external identity provider.

For Azure  [Link-1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial) and [Link-2](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on) on federating gcp with azure ad configuring provisioning and SSO.